# Cancancan not letting right users create, update, or delete -- in weird ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

I am using Devise and cancancan. I have Book model and Post model. After applying cancancan, in Book, limiting edit and delete to users matching user.id works fine. I can also create a book with no problem. Within each book, I can (or should be able to) create a post. Limiting edit and delete also works fine here. But when I create a post a a logged-in user who created the book for this post, it says I am not allowed to do so.

When I get rid of "load_and_" below, I can create post, but so can other users who should not be able to.

posts controller:

```rb
    load_and_authorize_resource :nested => :book
```

ability.rb (I initially had "manage" instead of CRUD, but in trying different things spelled out each of the CRUD; neither worked):

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.present?
      can [:create, :read, :update, :destroy], Book, user_id: user.id
      can :read, Book

      can [:create, :read, :update, :destroy], Post, book: { user_id: user.id } 
      can :read, Post
    end
```

routes.rb:

```rb
  resources :books do
    resources :posts, shallow: true
  end

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end

  resources :users do
    resources :comments, shallow: true 
  end
```

...since I'm asking a question, let me add another related one just in case someone feels like answering:

I have the following code to show or not show edit/delete on a post. They seem to show no matter which user is looking at them. On Book list, they are hidden or shown well. Not sure why it's not working here.

```
    <td>
        <% if can? :update, Post %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%if can? :destroy, Post %>
            <%= link_to 'Destroy', {:controller => :posts,
              :action => 'destroy', :id => post },
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
```

UPDATE

After I changed load_and_authorize_resource on posts controller to:

```rb
    load_and_authorize_resource :book
    load_and_authorize_resource :post, through: :book
```

I can now create a post, with auth appropriately set. But now I can't edit or delete.

...any ideas?

The error message highlights:

```rb
          raise AccessDenied.new(nil, authorization_action, resource_class) # maybe this should be a record not found error instead?
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace:

```rb
load_and_authorize_resource :post, through: :book
```

in the posts controller with:

```rb
load_and_authorize_resource :post, through: :book, :shallow => true
```

because my nested routes for book and post (shown in my question) are shallow.

But I can still see edit/delete on other users' posts... Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

The solution for seeing edit/delete was to change

```rb
<% if can? :update, Post %>
```

to

```rb
<% if can? :update, post %>
```

because it is part of

```rb
<% @book.posts.each do |post| %>
```

Obvious, but should have matched the model going into can? with the model referred.